# Validación de Login con php y sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, login

Buen día, estoy realizando un sistema de login este es la parte del formulario en mi html

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
            <label>usuario</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Escriba su usuario" class="login" autocomplete="off"><br>
            <label>contraseña</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="passwd" placeholder="Escriba su contraseña" class="login" autocomplete="off"><br>
            <label>servicio</label><br>
                <select name="servicio" class="lista" id="lista"> 
                 <option value="0" selected>Eliga su servicio</option>
                 <option value="Cardiologia">Cardiología</option> 
                 <option value="Cirugia">Cirugia</option>
              <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn" name="insert"> 
       <br>
```

Y el código de PHP lo tengo escrito de la siguiente forma

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['insert'])){

        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = md5($_POST['passwd']);
        $servicio = $_POST['servicio'];

    $consultar = sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT usuario,password,servicio FROM usuario WHERE 
    usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$password' AND servicio = '$servicio'");

        if(!$consultar){
            echo 'Datos incorrectos';
        }else{
            header("Location:cardio.php");

    }

    }
?>
```

Tal como lo tengo, no importa que datos escriba en los Inputs, siempre me dirige a cardio.php, no hace la validación con la base de datos. Agradecería cualquier ayuda o comentario sobre el código.

Comment: En el formulario html creo que te falta cerrar una etiqueta select. Y respecto al codigo PHP, ¿por qué compruebas si el botón de submit está establecido? Cuando realizas la consulta, ¿has comprobado qué te devuelve la variable $consultar?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el $consultar solo devuelve FALSE si es erróneo, pero si el query esta ok va a devolver los campos del query sin rows.

Deberías consultar de la siguiente manera

```
if(!sqlsrv_next_result($consultar)){
    echo 'Datos incorrectos';
}else{
    header("Location:cardio.php");

}
```

Si necesitas ver lo que tiene el query que se ejecuta en la base de datos y comparar si el mismo deuelve o no registros quedaría asi:

```
echo "SELECT usuario,password,servicio FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$password' AND servicio = '$servicio'";
if(!sqlsrv_next_result($consultar)){
    echo 'Datos incorrectos';
}else{
    header("Location:cardio.php");
}
```

De esa manera en la pantalla podrás ver lo que viene por POST y como se arma el query para probar si esta todo en orden.

Otra manera que puedes resolverlo es contando la cantidad de registros que devuelve el query. Si la cantidad de registros es mayor a 0 quiere decir que el usuario y contraseña que buscas es correcta.

Ejemplo:

```
if(sqlsrv_num_rows($consultar) > 0){
    echo 'Datos incorrectos';
}else{
    header("Location:cardio.php");
}
```

Espero te sea útil

Comment: Al agregar la parte de (!sqlsrv_next_result($consultar) me manda siempre el echo de datos incorrectos, aunque los datos estén bien

Comment: Deberías revisar si el query al SQLServer  esta bien armado y probarlo en la base de datos ya que el sqlsrv_next_result devuelve TRUE si puede mover el cursor y FALSE si no hay nada.   Si haces un echo "SELECT usuario,password,servicio FROM usuario WHERE 
    usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$password' AND servicio = '$servicio'" podras ver el mismo en pantalla y si estan llegando bien los datos por POST y el query a ejecutar a la base

Comment: Al hacer el echo del SELECT solo me aparece Resource id #6 la verdad no se lo que signifique =/

Comment: edité mi respuesta para ver si el echo lo estamos ejecutando de la misma manera

Comment: Lo escribí como me comentaste en la edición de la respuesta, el echo de la información esta ok, pero aun así me marca datos incorrectos, aunque según yo, si estan correctos

Comment: Vuelvo a editar con otra opcion.

Comment: Con esa opción ya no importa si son correctos o incorrectos, todos me dejan entrar, no se si tenga algo que ver el tipo de datos que entra desde php a la base de datos. En mi base los datos están definidos en varchar, tendrá algo que ver?

Comment: Me puedes copiar aqui lo que te muestra el echo en la pantalla ?

Comment: SELECT usuario,password,servicio FROM usuario WHERE usuario = Arturo Gutierrez Hernandez AND password = fb786dbd9274db43a9e3715d5193253b AND servicio = CirugiaDatos incorrectos

Comment: te puedo recomendar que el query lo escribas concatenando las variables ?. Quedaría asi:   "SELECT usuario,password,servicio FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '". $usuario ."' AND password = '". $password ."' AND servicio = '". $servicio ."'"

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, estoy empezando a darme por vencido, no se en que esta fallando

Comment: Estamos haciendo la manera correcta, empiezo a suponer que el problema pase por otro lado.  No se como puedo ayudarte ..

Answer (score 1):

Prueba colocando "'$variable'"

```
$consultar = sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT usuario,password,servicio FROM usuario WHERE 
usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$password' AND servicio = '$servicio'");
```

Realiza una prueba con que arroje la consulta en sel sql server.
Ej: echo $consulta. El resultado lo ejecutas en el sql server.

Comment: Ejecute el resultado del echo en sql server y la consulta esta bien, no entiendo por que al momento de ejecutarse en php no valida que la información existe en la base de datos

Comment: Verifica en el php.ini del apache s tienes habilitada la extensión del sql server.

Comment: Si esta habilitada, uso la extensión para hacer el conect a la base de datos y ese funciona sin problemas

Comment: haz un var_dump($consultar) y me dices que trae.

Comment: bool(false) es lo que aparece

Comment: Quiere decir que no trae resultados.

Comment: Revisases la cadena de conexión?

Comment: $con de donde sale?

Comment: $con es una función en mi archivo de conexion.php, hice el include al inicio del archivo